# How to initialize Mongodb in NextJS startup

Tags: mongodb, next.js, initialization, connection, startup

As you know NextJS is Jamstack framework and I'm migrating from node/express to it but my problem is how to connect server to database at startup of server as i did in express?
there is now where to put my initalizing code in NextJS? Am I saying correct?
I saw some code to to that but there were typescript codes that im not familiar with them

On the other hand i'm able to do that on serverside functions like `getStaticProps` or `getServerSideProps` this is my code
dbinit.js

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
export const dbStatus = () => mongoose.connection.readyState;
export default function dbConnect() {
  if (dbStatus == 1) return "database is connected";
  mongoose.connect(
    `mongodb://localhost:${process.env.DBPORT}/${process.env.DBNAME}`
  );
}
```

index.js

```
export async function getServerSideProps() {
  const result = await dbConnect();
  console.log(dbStatus());
  return {
    props: {},
  };
}
```

with this code im able to connect to mongodb but there are some problems and the most important is that mycode isnot cleancode

Answer (score 4):

In NextJS, we can connect MongoDB as middleware. This is very similar to the Express middleware approach as shown below.

```js
// middleware/database.js

import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb';
import nextConnect from 'next-connect';

const client = new MongoClient('{YOUR-MONGODB-CONNECTION-STRING}', {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
});

async function database(req, res, next) {
  if (!client.isConnected()) await client.connect();
  req.dbClient = client;
  req.db = client.db('MCT');
  return next();
}

const middleware = nextConnect();

middleware.use(database);

export default middleware;
```

For more details, you can refer to this official [how-to doc](https://www.mongodb.com/developer/how-to/nextjs-building-modern-applications/) for step-by-step guidance. [Here](https://github.com/kukicado/building-modern-app-with-nextjs-and-mongodb) is the example repository used.